# Entire functions and zeros in the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function with zeros $z_{1}, z_{2}, \ldots$. Is it true that only finitely many zeros lie in the open unit disc? If so why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unit disc is compact, hence the zeros accumulate there. Now use the [Identity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Comment: (To be precise, the *closed* unit disc is compact.)

Comment: Thanks Hans! It's important here that the function is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the unit disc.